# How to add custom text to a cell based on a specific entry in a different cell?

Tags: excel, vba

My laboratory is capable of running 20+ different analyses, and we get contracts from about the same 15 companies to do a combination of these analyses. I created an Excel spread sheet to keep track of the work as it comes in, where columns are the 20 different analyses we can run, and rows are the companies. I type in either a checkmark or "NA", depending on whether that company requests that specific analysis. (Each company requests its own combination of analyses).

I need some help with the following:

If I enter "Company 1" in cell A100, I want cell B100 to display "NA". If I enter "Company 2" instead, I want cell D100 to display "NA". And if I enter "Company 3", do nothing, for example. I am OK with adding the check marks manually, as there are other variables that need not be mentioned.

Now, I have been able to develop some toy solution in VBA to some extent (please see code below). However, I have two issues:

1. In order to run the code, I have to switch to the VBA editor and press F5 after every entry. Instead, I would like it to work like when using formulas for the cells. In other words, if I type in "Company 1" in any cell of column A and hit "Enter", I would like the "NA" to display automatically in the appropriate cells on the row. I guess I could record a macro for this, but the file is shared with many people and I would prefer to avoid that.
2. In the future I will need to add more companies and analyses, so I need a code I can quickly go in and update. Or maybe have a list of companies that I add to and link it somehow to my code.

   ```
   Sub writeNA()
   For i = 1 To 20 Step 1

   x = Cells(i, 1).Value

   If x = "Company 1" Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "NA"
   End If

   If x = "Company 2" Then
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA"
   End If

   If x = "Company 3" Then
    Cells(i, 4).Value = "NA"
   End If

   Next
   End Sub
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: 1. If you want your code to run when a change is made to a specific range of cells, you can have a look at the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

Comment: @DecimalTurn Yes that is very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: 2. It depends on your preferences. You could do that with code only, but I would advise to at least look into the Select Case statement to have a more compact code and skip further checks once you have a match. You could also have the information inside a table located in your spreadsheet and use a lookup function inside VBA to check for a match in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Cells When Entering Values (Worksheet Change Event)

- Usually the code has to be copied to different modules (if you want to use it in multiple worksheets). Optionally you can copy both codes into the sheet module.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- No need to run anything, it runs automatically.
- If you already have values in the `Criteria Column` then do a `copy/paste` and the data will get updated.

**Sheet module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    updateCompany Me, Target
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateCompany( _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        Target As Range)
        
    Const ProcName As String = ""
    On Error GoTo clearError

    Const CompanyList As String = "Company 1,Company 2,Company 3"
    Const ColsList As String = "B,D,"
    Const CriteriaList As String = "NA,NA,"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const CritCol As String = "A"
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Define Processing Range (First Cell to Bottom-Most Cell (1048576)).
    Set rng = ws.Columns(CritCol) _
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1) _
        .Offset(FirstRow - 1)
    
    ' Define Last Non-Empty Cell.
    Set cel = rng.Find( _
        What:="*", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    ' Validate Last Non-Empty Cell
    ' i.e. check if Processing Range contains a value.
    If cel Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Define Source Range (First Cell to Last Non-Empty Cell).
    Set rng = rng.Resize(cel.Row - rng.Row + 1)
    
    ' Define Target Range.
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, rng)
    ' Validate Target Range i.e. check if the change happened in Source Range.
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit ' Change didn't happen in Source Range.
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Company List to Company Array.
    Dim Company() As String: Company = Split(CompanyList, ",")
    ' Write values from Columns List to Columns Array.
    Dim Cols() As String: Cols = Split(ColsList, ",")
    ' Write values from Criteria List to Criteria Array.
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Write values to cells in rows of changed cells.

    Dim CurrentMatch As Variant
    ' Loop through cells of Target Range (can be non-contiguous).
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        ' Check if current cell is not blank (Empty or "").
        If Len(cel.Value) > 0 Then
            ' Try to find the value in current cell (Company) in Company Array.
            CurrentMatch = Application.Match(cel.Value, Company, 0)
            ' If found...
            If IsNumeric(CurrentMatch) Then
                ' Define the current index of the found value.
                CurrentMatch = CurrentMatch - 1 ' -1 because 0-based.
                ' Check if the value in Columns Array is different than "".
                If Cols(CurrentMatch) <> "" Then
                    ' Write value from Criteria Array to cell in current row
                    ' of the column found in Columns Array.
                    Cells(cel.Row, Cols(CurrentMatch)) = Criteria(CurrentMatch)
                Else
                    ' The value in Columns Array is "".
                End If
            Else
                ' Couldn't find Company name in Company Array.
            End If
        Else
            ' Cell is blank or empty.
        End If
    Next cel

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a Worksheet Change event handler, so that whenever the worksheet is changed, the function runs and adds "NA" where needed.

Here is the function that I used for proof of concept. It also adds "NA" when "Company 3" is entered (not sure if that is desired or not).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Text
    Case "Company 1", "Company 2", "Company 3"
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Value2 = "NA"
End Select
End Sub
```